# NSHashTable with weak references

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, ios7, ios6

I want to to use a NSHashTable for keeping weak references to the contained objects. Regarding other customizable behaviors(including equality check), I want the exact same behavior as NSSet(so practically I want to have a NSSet with weak references). Can you give me an example on how to initialize such a hash table?

Would following suffice:
`[NSHashTable hashTableWithOptions:NSPointerFunctionsWeakMemory]`

Also will NSHashTable with weak references automatically remove de-allocated objects?

Comment: You should note that NSHashTable is only available in OSX and not iOS.

Comment: @SandyChapman `NSHashTable` has been available on iOS since 6.0. Check the `NSHashTable.h` header.

Comment: @DrBeardface Interesting that [the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/NSHashTable_class/Introduction/Introduction.html) doesn't say its supported then. **EDIT:** Looks like I'm looking at the wrong docs. [This one](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/NSHashTable_class/Introduction/Introduction.html) says it is supported.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, you can use NSPointerFunctionsWeakMemory. Facebook KVOController also use NSHashTable with that option, see [KVOController](https://github.com/facebook/KVOController/blob/master/FBKVOController/FBKVOController.m)

```
- (instancetype)init
{
  self = [super init];
  if (nil != self) {
    NSHashTable *infos = [NSHashTable alloc];
#ifdef __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED
    _infos = [infos initWithOptions:NSPointerFunctionsWeakMemory|NSPointerFunctionsObjectPointerPersonality capacity:0];
#elif defined(__MAC_OS_X_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED)
    if ([NSHashTable respondsToSelector:@selector(weakObjectsHashTable)]) {
      _infos = [infos initWithOptions:NSPointerFunctionsWeakMemory|NSPointerFunctionsObjectPointerPersonality capacity:0];
    } else {
      // silence deprecated warnings
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wdeprecated-declarations"
      _infos = [infos initWithOptions:NSPointerFunctionsZeroingWeakMemory|NSPointerFunctionsObjectPointerPersonality capacity:0];
#pragma clang diagnostic pop
    }

#endif
    _lock = OS_SPINLOCK_INIT;
  }
  return self;
}
```

Also, for more convenient way, you can use `weakObjectsHashTable`

> Returns a new hash table for storing weak references to its contents.
>
> **Return Value** A new hash table that uses the options NSHashTableZeroingWeakMemory and NSPointerFunctionsObjectPersonality
>   and has an initial capacity of 0.

The document is a little bit old, but it is true. See [NSHipster NSHash​Table &
NSMap​Table](http://nshipster.com/nshashtable-and-nsmaptable/)

```
NSHashTableZeroingWeakMemory: This option has been deprecated. Instead use the NSHashTableWeakMemory option
```

Note also that

> NSHashTableWeakMemory Equal to NSPointerFunctionsWeakMemory